# VB.NET - Problems with Sendkey

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, sendkeys

i have a problem with SendKeys.
I made a Keybinder for an online multiplayer game.
If a key e.g.: Numlock 1 is registred, my software sends the word or letters or whatever in textbox1.
everything works fine.
Example code:
My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys(Textbox1.text)

But if i register Numlock1 and Numlock2 and set the Sendkey Value of Numlock1 to "Hi" and the Value of Numlock2 to "It costs 100$" the software replaces the 1 in Numlock2 with the value of Numlock1.

I am from germany, my skills are not so good but i hope i have explained everything understandable :)

Stein

Comment: We would appreciate some codes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Numlock1" and "Numlock2" ???

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is no keyboard with the Numlock2 button, and I don't fully understand your question. Maybe you want to toggle the Numlock button?

Here's how to toggle [Numluck] in a VB.net application:

In Visual Studio 2013, compile this piece of open source code as a C# console application. The sendkey.exe can be used in a command window.

[sendkey v0.0.1](http://pastebin.com/raw/yWUTjUif)

In VB.net, make use of Sendkey v0.0.1 like this:

```
Public Class ExecVBNet
Shared Sub Execut(command as String, arguments as String, permanent as Boolean) 
    Dim p as Process = new Process() 
    Dim pi as ProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() 
    pi.Arguments = " " + if(permanent = true, "/K" , "/C") + " " + command + " " + arguments 
    pi.FileName = "cmd.exe" 
    p.StartInfo = pi 
    p.Start() 
End Sub
End Class
```

And press the numlock button like this. It is similar to pressing (down) and depressing (up) the button one time. The result is, the button is toggled.

```
ExecVBNet.Execut("Sendkey", "NUMLOCK down", true)
ExecVBNet.Execut("Sendkey", "NUMLOCK up", true)
```

In the Execut method, you can also directly use "sendkey.exe" instead of opening the console window with "cmd.exe"